# How to show correct current time in Status Bar Notification in Android?

Tags: android, notifications

I am using Status Bar Notification in my app and sending it on clicking a Button.But when Notification arrives, on opening it shows wrong date(in my case it is showing 1/1/1970).

[image: Notification]

I am using following code for showing Status Bar Notification.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Notify", 1000);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "TITLE", "MESSAGE", pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(R.id.button1, notification);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from my blog post here:
http://blog.blundellapps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

You should create your notification like this:

```
// This is the icon to use on the notification
int icon = R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;
// This is the scrolling text of the notification
CharSequence text = "Your notification time is upon us".
// What time to show on the notification
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);
```